# IllegalStateException: "WSEJBEndpointManager.ejbPostInvoke already called" while throwing @WebFault

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, websphere-8

I am currently migrating a webservice from Websphere 7 to Websphere 8.5.5.2
The application worked in version 7, but not completely in 8.5

It works in the happy path, but generates a IllegalStateException when I want to throw a SOAPFault.

I am happy to provide more information, but I am not sure what is relevant.

The **web.xml** version was 2.5, but I also tried version 3.0

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

The webservice is annotated using @javax.jws.WebService and uses a local ejb injection

```
@javax.ejb.Stateless
@javax.jws.WebService(endpointInterface = "com.example.DialogService", targetNamespace = "http://services.example.com/DialogService", serviceName = "DialogService", portName = "DialogService")
public class DialogServiceImpl {
  @EJB
  Service service;

  public DialogResponseType get(DialogRequestType dialogMessage) throws DialogMessageFault {
    try {
      DialogMsg response = service.process(dialogMessage);
      return response.respond();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      DialogMessageFault dialogMessageFault = new DialogMessageFault(SERVICE_ERROR, e);
      throw dialogMessageFault;
    }
  }
}
```

The exception:

```
@javax.xml.ws.WebFault(name = "messageFault", targetNamespace = "http://services.example.com/DialogService")
public class DialogMessageFault extends Exception
```

Stacktrace:

```
AxisEngine    E 
  org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine receive java.lang.IllegalStateException: WSEJBEndpointManager.ejbPostInvoke already called.
  org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WSEJBEndpointManager.ejbPostInvoke already called.
  at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
  at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:242)
  at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:212)
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
  at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1583)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3837)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WSEJBEndpointManager.ejbPostInvoke already called.
  at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
  at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
  at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
  at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.responseReady(EndpointController.java:710)
  at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.handleResponse(EndpointController.java:439)
  at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.invoke(EndpointController.java:130)
  at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:161)
  ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WSEJBEndpointManager.ejbPostInvoke already called.
  at com.ibm.ejs.container.WSEJBWrapper.ejbPostInvoke(WSEJBWrapper.java:246)
  at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.server.WSEJBInvocationListener.responseReady(WSEJBInvocationListener.java:416)
  at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.server.WSEJBInvocationListener.notify(WSEJBInvocationListener.java:102)
  at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.responseReady(EndpointController.java:707)
  ... 32 more
```

Comment: This appears to be a product issue.  I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the application used an extra setting to prevent this exact exception in an earlier version of Websphere. Removal of this setting fixed the problem:

com.ibm.websphere.websvcs.EJBPostInvokeCallOnException

See: [IBM PM59231](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM59231)